# What is the area of the region inside the limacon with equation $r=3+2 \sin (\theta)$ that lies below the line $y=x$?

Tags: calculus, riemannian-geometry, polar-coordinates, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

What is the area of the region inside the limacon with equation $r=3+2 \sin (\theta)$ that lies below the line $y=x$?

---

I know I should use Riemann sum but how to write the equation?  And what about the $y=x$?

Comment: I believe you can consider this as the area of the limacon bounded by  the two rays $\theta = 45$ and $\theta = 225$ from which you can simply plug into the integral formula for polar coordinates shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29)

Comment: or, possibly, from $\theta=-3/4 \pi$ to $\theta=1/4 \pi$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Notice that, as mentioned in the comments as well, the line is a combination of the rays corresponding to $\displaystyle \theta = \frac{π}{4}$ and $\displaystyle \theta = -\frac{3π}{4}$.

Just reminding you, polar curves are traced out by *angle*, and so are their integrals.

We have that the area enclosed by the two rays $\theta=a$ and $\theta=b$, the origin, and $r=f(\theta)$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b f(\theta)^2 \,d\theta$.

We have the rays $\displaystyle \theta = \frac{π}{4}$ and $\displaystyle \theta = -\frac{3π}{4}$ and $r=f(\theta)=3+2\sin(\theta)$.

We have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac{3π}{4}}^{\frac{π}{4}}(3+2\sin(\theta))^2\,d\theta=\boxed{\frac{11π}{2}-6\sqrt{2}}$ units$^2$.

Comment: Your $-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ should be $-\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$.